# VLOOKUP with both 3- and 4-character postcode districts

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have downloaded a database of UK postcodes and want to use `VLOOKUP` to get the district name from the postcode. I currently have it working with three character postcode districts but some may be four characters so I want the `VLOOKUP` to search for the 4-character postcode district and if not look for the 3-character postcode district.

Here is my basic code that works for 4-character postcode districts:

```
 =VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2,4)&"*",Postcodes!A2:C3108,3,FALSE)
```

So I search for `TW13` (Feltham) it works fine, but breaks if I just search for `TW1` (Richmond).

Using ISERROR causes incorrect information:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2,4)&"*",Postcodes!A2:C3108,3,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2,3)&"*",Postcodes!A2:C3108,3,FALSE))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that and it throws up problems, ive edited my code

Comment: Sorry was being stupid I did iserror not iferror!! thank you

Comment: If you search for 3 you should use `LEFT(F2,3)`. So  like pnuts suggested, wrap a ` IFERROR` around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the location of the Space.

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2,FIND(" ",F2)-1)&"*",PostCodes!A2:C3108,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: I've found that appending a space off the right side of the value used in the [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) helps avoid errors thrown when a space might not otherwise exist and does not affect the outcome if one already exists. e.g. `FIND(" ",F2&" ")`. It only has to be used with the values in the FIND; not in the LEFT.

Comment: UK postal codes are even worse than Canadian ones and whose to say there isn't a few in the 'database' that have no space at all.

Comment: @pnuts - Having worked with fairly large data sets (e.g. North American Yellow pages, 9 years of US gov't GSA data, Canadian postal code-to-lat/long CA gov't census database, etc) I can honestly say that data formats are not always what they should be.